# Opening in fullscreen on Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, fullscreen

In my user settings I have

```
  "window.newWindowDimensions": "fullscreen",
```

My expectation is that this will open fullscreen -- i.e. a new virtual screen to the right of my other virtual screens.  But instead it opens maximised -- it opens on the Desktop screen with a window a maximum size.  There is no difference between the "maximized" and "fullscreen" settings.

How do I get vscode to actually open Full Screen when using `code .` to open it from a terminal?

Comment: smells like bug: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/181308

Comment: I agree.  bpasero doesn't seem to though, and he closed the issue...

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/181326 has been raised and needs votes to be actioned.  It seems "A setting to force a window opening fullscreen does not exist today", despite the "fullscreen" value...